# Google Sheets: generating a filtered array and doing a sumif in the same formula

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs, array-formulas

I have a document with a column (`'Source'!D:D`) built with this formatting:

```
Country → Name → ID
Country → Name → ID
Country → Name → ID
Country → Name → ID
```

In the same document, there's another column (`'Source'!AA:AA`) with numbers. I'd like to sum the numbers if the Country in `ColD` is for example USA. I can't add columns in the `Source` document, so I need to generate an array with the countries already "polished" inside the formula.
I've tried with this, but it's not working. The ARRAYFORMULA and REGEXTRACT definitely work (the standalone bit indeed generates an array with only country names), but I think the 2 criteria "don't talk to each other", they're like separated bits, not referring to the same row anymore.

```
=SUMIFS('Source'!$AA$100:$AA,arrayformula(REGEXEXTRACT(ARRAYFORMULA('Source'!$D$100:$D), "^(.+?)→")),"USA")
```

How can I change the formula above to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your formula is correct (the inner arrayformula is unnecessary, but it does not harm). It also works correctly with sample data in my spreadsheet. The problem has to be in the data; perhaps the country names are followed by a space before the arrow?

But I also recommend taking a slightly different approach, with `filter` and `regexmatch`:

```
=sum(filter('Source'!$AA$100:$AA, regexmatch('Source'!$D$100:$D, "^USA\b")))
```

This has simpler logic (match vs extract), so should be easier to debug.

Comment: Yep, it works! A strange thing is happening though with SUM and FILTER if used with IMPORTRANGE.. I'm trying with: `=(
SUM(filter(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXX","Source'!$Z$3298:$Z"), regexmatch(IMPORTRANGE("XXXXXX","'Source'!$D$3298:$D"), "^USA\b"))))` but it's returning `No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.`. I have used FILTER and COUNTIF in the past with multiple IMPORTRANGEs, without any issues. Maybe it can't be used with SUM..?

Comment: I don't know; try the formula without `sum` and see what happens.